# Android : imageview over imageview issue

Tags: android

I using following code in my layout , i want to show both image , (image over another image)
But i see just one image on screen

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/splash_bg_gradient"
   android:id="@+id/splash_gradient"
   tools:context="com.android.abc.activity.SplashActivity" >

   <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/splash_logo" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center" 
       android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
       android:contentDescription="@string/desc_splash_graphics"/>
   <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/splash_image" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:scaleType = "fitXY" 
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
       android:contentDescription="@string/desc_splash_graphics"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **FrameLayout** instead of *RelativeLayout*. RelativeLayout should only be used for complex layouts, it's much heavier than FrameLayout also.

```
     <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/splash_bg_gradient"
     android:id="@+id/splash_gradient"
     tools:context="com.android.abc.activity.SplashActivity" >

     <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/splash_logo" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center" 
         android:contentDescription="@string/desc_splash_graphics"/>
     <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/splash_image" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:scaleType = "fitXY" 
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:contentDescription="@string/desc_splash_graphics"/>

     </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I cannot use centerInParent in FrameLayout ?what it the instead

Comment: gravity="center"  should be enough.

Comment: Why i getting force close when i use FrameLayout ?

Comment: You may still be casting it to a relativeLayout in your code

Comment: @user3929483 `gravity=center` will not work. Use `android:layout_gravity="center"` on both `ImageViews`.

Comment: yes yes this is what i meant actually. android:layout_gravity="center"

Comment: I fixed force close error as your help , but i see just one image still (bigger image)

Comment: @user3929483 Ordering is important. The smaller image should be defined _after_ the bigger image in your xml. If this doesn't help, post your updated layout in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/splash_bg_gradient"
   android:id="@+id/splash_gradient"
   tools:context="com.android.abc.activity.SplashActivity" >

   <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/splash_image" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:scaleType = "fitXY" 
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
       android:contentDescription="@string/desc_splash_graphics"/>
   <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/splash_logo" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
       android:contentDescription="@string/desc_splash_graphics"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Elements in a `RelativeLayout` are displayed in order of their declaration.

Comment: Ok... so define which image you want to see over the other. Also you specified a background to the `RelativeLayout`, but one of the picture id going to cover the whole screen, so you won't see `@drawable/splash_bg_gradient`.

Comment: i dont need to splash gradient , i setting it to null in my java code.